# TimeoutException undetected_chromedriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, undetected-chromedriver

I have a web scraper using python with undetected_chromedriver. It is installed in a Windows Server 2016 from Amazon Lightsail. I am using RDP to access the server and to execute the script in cmd. When I execute the script it works perfectly fine, but when I close the RDP session, after a couple of minutes it raises TimeoutException from WebDriverWait.until. It seems like it can't find the element when I close the RDP.

```
def wait_vis(driver: uc.Chrome, seconds: float):
    WebDriverWait(driver, seconds).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'ia- 
        ThreeBounces')]"))
)
```

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the element.

Comment: It is hard to catch the html of the element because it is a loading modal. It only shows for max 2 seconds and then disappear.

Comment: or provide the url of your website

Comment: This is one of the urls: https://employers.indeed.com/hiring-insights?q=Cook&month=202211&l=Greenville%2C+SC&country=US